# SQL Server : error insert query

Tags: sql-server, pdo

I have an issue with a SQL Server column quote number which not accept more than 5 digits. 5 digits or below it is working fine, but above 5 digits, it is causing an error:

> xx.xx.xx.xx didn’t send any data.
>   ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Example - quote number `12345` is working fine, but `123456` causes the error.

I have also changed bindParam to bindValue in query but not result.

**Connection**:

```
try {
    $proconn = new PDO("dblib:host=$servername;dbname=TableQuote;charset=UTF-8", $username, $password);

    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $proconn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo "Connection failed" . $e->getMessage;
}
```

Variable data:

```
//$quote_number="123456";
[quote_noumber] => '12345'
[inside_sales] => 'Pat Zerphy'
[outside_sales] => 'SEL102'
[customer_code] => 'SEL101'
[custome_name] => 'Selex Systems Inegrations'
[customer_contact] => 'Bob Smith'
[quote_details] => 'Misc coax cable assemblies.
1/2" Superflex, 1/4" Superflex'
[rna_location] => '1'
[number_of_line_items] => '25'
[created] => '1468291705'
```

Insert query:

```
try {
    $prosql = $proconn->prepare("insert into dbo.QuoteRecord(quote_number,customer_code,customer_name,rna_location,inside_sale,outside_sale,customer_contact,quote_detail,number_of_line_items,created)VALUES(:quote_number,:customer_code,:customer_name,:rna_location,:inside_sale,:outside_sale,:customer_contact,:quote_detail,:number_of_line_items,:created)");

    $prosql->bindParam(':quote_number',$quote_number);
    $prosql->bindParam(':customer_code',$customer_code);
    $prosql->bindParam(':customer_name',$customer_name);
    $prosql->bindParam(':rna_location',$rna_location);
    $prosql->bindParam(':inside_sale',$inside_sale);
    $prosql->bindParam(':outside_sale',$outside_sale);
    $prosql->bindParam(':customer_contact',$customer_contact);
    $prosql->bindParam(':quote_detail',$quote_detail);
    $prosql->bindParam(':number_of_line_items',$number_of_line_items);
    $prosql->bindParam(':created',$created);

    $prosql->execute();
}
catch ( PDOException $e ) {
    print( "Error connecting to SQL Server." );
    die(print_r($e));
}
```

Data types:

```
Array
(
    [TABLE_CATALOG] => TableQuote
    [0] => proALPHA
    [TABLE_SCHEMA] => dbo
    [1] => dbo
    [TABLE_NAME] => QuoteRecord
    [2] => QuoteRecord
    [COLUMN_NAME] => quote_number
    [3] => quote_number
    [ORDINAL_POSITION] => 2
    [4] => 2
    [COLUMN_DEFAULT] => 
    [5] => 
    [IS_NULLABLE] => YES
    [6] => YES
    [DATA_TYPE] => varchar
    [7] => varchar
    [CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH] => 128
    [8] => 128
    [CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH] => 128
    [9] => 128
    [NUMERIC_PRECISION] => 
    [10] => 
    [NUMERIC_PRECISION_RADIX] => 
    [11] => 
    [NUMERIC_SCALE] => 
    [12] => 
    [DATETIME_PRECISION] => 
    [13] => 
    [CHARACTER_SET_CATALOG] => 
    [14] => 
    [CHARACTER_SET_SCHEMA] => 
    [15] => 
    [CHARACTER_SET_NAME] => iso_1
    [16] => iso_1
    [COLLATION_CATALOG] => 
    [17] => 
    [COLLATION_SCHEMA] => 
    [18] => 
    [COLLATION_NAME] => SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
    [19] => SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
    [DOMAIN_CATALOG] => 
    [20] => 
    [DOMAIN_SCHEMA] => 
    [21] => 
    [DOMAIN_NAME] => 
    [22] => 
)
```

Comment: What's the error you are getting BTW?

Comment: Either you have the necessary feedback you havr not yet posted or you probably should run some tests. Such as violating constraints? Inserting invalid datatypes? Invalid connections and so on. Because SQL Server gives great feedback, if you can get it.

Answer (score 1):

> Example - quote number - 12345 working fine but 123456 it giving
>   error.

if that's the case then most probably it's because of the column size definition for column `quote_number`. Looks like it's a `VARCHAR` column and if it is still not wrong you have set its size to `VARCHAR(5)` probably.

Post your table definition or schema for `dbo.QuoteRecord` table.